# My super simple UICollectionView is not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a simple collection view. I've got my custom cell "SectionCell" and the my custom class "Section", which contains two @IBOutlet properties: titleLabel and imageView. Both of these properties are hooked up to their respective storyboard views.

In storyboard, the collectionView scene has been linked to the MenuVC.swift file, which inherits from UICollectionView. The Cell view is linked to SectionCell. And I've set the cell's Identifier to "Section".

For debugging purposes I've set the view.backgroundColor to black and the cell's contentView background color to teal. Yet when I run the the simulator neither show. I get a white background and all that appears is the view title. Any ideas on what the fix is?

```
class MenuVC: UICollectionViewController {
    
    var sections = [Section]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Begin Learning"
        
        view.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    
    // MARK:- CollectionView Methods
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Section", for: indexPath) as? SectionCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue SectionCell ")
        }
        
        let section = sections[indexPath.item]
        cell.titleLabel.text = section.title
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: section.image)

        return cell
    }
}

class SectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
}

class Section: NSObject {
    
    var title: String
    var image: String
    
    init(title: String, image: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpBOO.png)

I'm also quite new to posting questions on SO. If you have any tips on how to better format questions, I'm all ears!

Comment: Check if `cellForItemAt` is being called - add a print statement in there

Comment: Did you set the custom class for the scene?

Comment: cellForItem is not being called, and yes I did set the custom class "MenuVC" to the UICollectionView scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

LOL you really do need eagle eyes as a developer. This:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

is supposed to be:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

And voila!

Answer (score 0):

make outlet of your collectionview and give it to the delegate and data source...

make outlet like this in your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionview!
```

then put this code in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.relaodData()
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However, I think it is best suited to the scenario where I am using a regular UIViewController. Instead I opted for a UICollectionViewController which already comes with a collectionView property and conveniently already has the delegate and dataSource already assigned to itself.

Answer (score 0):

have you implemented the following protocol?

[UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout)

```
extension MenuVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: 300.0, height: 300.0) // and set size for each item inside this function.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am familiar with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, but was under the impression that it was optional. In past projects I've been able to forgo it and still get the collection view to render.

Comment: Ignore when you have set the estimatedItemSize to automatic (UICollectionViewFlowLayout) and use the self size for each Cell

Comment: In Storyboard I have estimatedItemSize set to automatic. Not sure what you mean by 'and use the self size for each Cell'... However, I'm now getting the error: "'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter". I should also point out that in my storyboard view hierarchy I can see 'Collection View Flow Layout' with a yellow cube next to it.